# How to refer to a bibtex entry within shorthand?

Tags: biblatex, archaeologie

This might be tricky and I am sure there is a better solution than the one I came up with (or actually didn’t come up with).

I have a book which consists of a text-volume and a picture-volume, so I have three entries (the fourth entry is only for testing to have a label with a letter). But with `@MvBook` I only have the main-entry in my bibliography and the child-entries related to it.

What I would like to do is citing e.g. the text-volume in respect to the label of the parent-entry: In this case `MOR 1893a|1` or `MOR 1893a|1, 123`. But somehow the page-sequence is repeated.

Happy to take any solution getting the result `[shortauthor of child-entry] [labelyear of the parent-entry]|[volume of child-entry], [page]`

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{filecontents,babel}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvBook{MOR-0,
  author        = {Ohnefalsch-Richter, Max},
  shortauthor = {MOR},
  year          = {1893},
  title     = {Kypros, die Bibel und Homer},
  volumes        = {2},
  publisher     = {A. Asher und Co.},
  location      = {Berlin},
  related = {MOR-1,MOR-2},
  relatedtype = {multivolume},
}

@Book{MOR-1,
  author        = {Ohnefalsch-Richter, Max},
  title         = {Text},
  volume        = {1},
  shortauthor = {MOR},
  crossref = {MOR-0},
  shorthand = {\cite{MOR-0}|1},
  options = {skipbib,skiplab}
}

@Book{MOR-2,
  author        = {Ohnefalsch-Richter, Max},
  title         = {Tafeln},
  volume        = {2},
shortauthor = {MOR},
  shorthand = {\cite{MOR-0}|2},
  crossref = {MOR-0},
  options = {skipbib,skiplab}
}

@mvBook{MOR-X,
  author        = {Ohnefalsch-Richter, Max},
  shortauthor = {MOR},
  year          = {1893},
  title     = {Kypros, the Bibel and Homer},
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[           
  backend=biber,
  style=archaeologie,
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareDataInheritance{mvbook}{book}{
  \noinherit{year}
  \inherit{label}{shorthand}
}

\begin{document}
\cite{MOR-0}\par
\cite[123]{MOR-1}\par
\cite[456]{MOR-2}\par
\cite{MOR-X}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like `\citeauthor` rather than `\cite`? Or `\citeyear` or `\citefield{shortauthor}` or whatever? `\cite` is going to try to give you a complete citation. Also, you say you have 3 entries, but you have 4. Are you sure it isn't 'Bible' rather than 'Bibel'? And I am not clear what you want in your bibliography: you say you 'only' have the parent entry and its children. But what else is there?

Comment: @cfr sorry, forgot to mention that the fourth entry is just to have label with a letter. With `citeauthor` or `\citeyear` I would not get the label with the lettered year (e.g. 1893a) I would only get e.g. 1893 [that’s why I included the fourth entry].

Comment: Yes, but you can cite just the label, which is what you want, in that case. `\cite` will do the lot - pre-note, post-note and all. You just want to pick out the particular bit you need. Thanks for the explanation re. the additional entry. That makes sense now.

Comment: `\citelabel` as with `shorthand = {\citelabel{MOR-0}|2}` will give me the bibtexkey of the parent-entry, not the appended year with letter?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very elegant, and perhaps not the best alternative, but the following builds somewhat literally your specified desired result:

```
shorthand = {\printnames{shortauthor}\nameyeardelim\entrydata{\thefield{crossref}}{\printlabeldateextra}|\printfield{volume}},
```

[image]

In full:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents,babel}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvBook{MOR-0,
  author        = {Ohnefalsch-Richter, Max},
  shortauthor = {MOR},
  year          = {1893},
  title     = {Kypros, die Bibel und Homer},
  volumes        = {2},
  publisher     = {A. Asher und Co.},
  location      = {Berlin},
  related = {MOR-1,MOR-2},
  relatedtype = {multivolume},
}

@Book{MOR-1,
  author        = {Ohnefalsch-Richter, Max},
  title         = {Text},
  volume        = {1},
  shortauthor = {MOR},
  crossref = {MOR-0},
  shorthand = {\printnames{shortauthor}\nameyeardelim\entrydata{\thefield{crossref}}{\printlabeldateextra}|\printfield{volume}},
  options = {skipbib,skiplab}
}

@Book{MOR-2,
  author        = {Ohnefalsch-Richter, Max},
  title         = {Tafeln},
  volume        = {2},
shortauthor = {MOR},
  shorthand = {\printnames{shortauthor}\nameyeardelim\entrydata{\thefield{crossref}}{\printlabeldateextra}|\printfield{volume}},
  crossref = {MOR-0},
  options = {skipbib,skiplab}
}

@mvBook{MOR-X,
  author        = {Ohnefalsch-Richter, Max},
  shortauthor = {MOR},
  year          = {1893},
  title     = {Kypros, the Bibel and Homer},
}

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[           
  backend=biber,
  style=archaeologie,
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareDataInheritance{mvbook}{book}{
  \noinherit{year}
  \inherit{label}{shorthand}
}

\begin{document}
\cite{MOR-0}\par
\cite[123]{MOR-1}\par
\cite[456]{MOR-2}\par
\cite{MOR-X}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: that works very fine the result is as expected and wanted. I am wondering if there is a smoother way?!

Comment: @LukasCB, well, the only thing that really needs to be supplied automatically is the dateextra part. I tried to avoid supplying info in duplicity, but you could well go with `shorthand = {MOR \entrydata{MOR-0}{\printlabeldateextra}|1}`. Still, as I said, someone might come up with something better/more elegant.